# Audio processing using AVFoundation Framework

Tags: ios, core-audio

I have one sound and i need to change the pitch and tempo of the sound how can i achieve this using Open-AL and Core Audio.
 i don't want to use any third party library for this purpose so can anyone help me to get started...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch iOS Audio Unit can independently change the pitch and tempo of Core Audio buffer streams, but it is not of very high quality (for instance, to the level of the best commercial solutions).  You will have to know how to configure Audio Units and set up an AUGraph.